# Flatten an RDD - Nested lists in value of key value pair

Tags: scala, apache-spark

It took me awhile to figure this out and I wanted to share my solution. Improvements are definitely welcome.

References: [Flattening a Scala Map in an RDD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835518/flattening-a-scala-map-in-an-rdd), [Spark Flatten Seq by reversing groupby, (i.e. repeat header for each sequence in it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24556813/spark-flatten-seq-by-reversing-groupby-i-e-repeat-header-for-each-sequence-in)

I have an RDD of the form: RDD[(Int, List[(String, List[(String, Int, Float)])])]

Key: Int

Value: List[(String, List[(String, Int, Float)])]

With a goal of flattening to: RDD[(Int, String, String, Int, Float)]

```
binHostCountByDate.foreach(println)
```

Gives the example:

```
(516361, List((2013-07-15, List((s2.rf.ru,1,0.5), (s1.rf.ru,1,0.5))), (2013-08-15, List((p.secure.com,1,1.0)))))
```

The final RDD should give the following

```
(516361,2013-07-15,s2.rf.ru,1,0.5)
(516361,2013-07-15,s1.rf.ru,1,0.5)
(516361,2013-08-15,p.secure.com,1,1.0)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple one-liner (and with destructuring in the for-comprehension we can use better names than _1, _2._1 etc which makes it easier to be sure we're getting the right result

```
// Use a outer list in place of an RDD for test purposes
val t = List((516361,
                 List(("2013-07-15", List(("s2.rf.ru,",1,0.5), ("s1.rf.ru",1,0.5))),
                      ("2013-08-15", List(("p.secure.com,",1,1.0))))))

t flatMap {case (k, xs) => for ((d, ys) <- xs; (dom, a,b) <-ys) yield (k, d, dom, a, b)}
   //> res0: List[(Int, String, String, Int, Double)] = 
       List((516361,2013-07-15,s2.rf.ru,,1,0.5),
            (516361,2013-07-15,s1.rf.ru,1,0.5),
            (516361,2013-08-15,p.secure.com,,1,1.0))
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach is as follows:

I flatten the first key value pair. This "removes" the first list.

```
val binHostCountForDate = binHostCountByDate.flatMapValues(identity)
```

Gives me an RDD of the form: RDD[(Int, (String, List[(String, Int, Float)])]

```
binHostCountForDate.foreach(println)

(516361,(2013-07-15,List((s2.rf.ru,1,0.5), (s1.rf.ru,1,0.5))))
(516361,(2013-08-15,List(p.secure.com,1,1.0))
```

Now I map the first two items into a tuple creating a new key and the second tuple as the value. Then apply the same procedure as above to flatten on the new key value pair.

```
val binDataRemapKey = binHostCountForDate.map(f =>((f._1, f._2._1), f._2._2)).flatMapValues(identity)
```

This gives the flattened RDD: RDD[(Int, String),(String, Int, Float)]

If this form is fine then we are done but we can go one step further and remove the tuples to get the final form we were originally looking for.

```
val binData = binDataRemapKey.map(f => (f._1._1, f._1._2, f._2._1, f._2._2, f._2._3))
```

This gives us the final form of: RDD[(Int, String, String, Int, Float)]

We now have a flattened RDD that has preserved the parents of each list.